# Type conversion and casting

Tags: rust, casting, type-conversion

I am beginner in rust. I have simple script but I have to use too much type casting.
Point of script: search clusters of neighbour cels with the same value in matrix (using flood fill algo with queue https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

This is full code:

```rust
fn find_clusters(playground: [[u8; SIZE]; SIZE]) -> Vec<Cluster> {
    
    let directions_cluster: [[i8; 2]; 4] = [[0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0]];
    
    let mut clusters: Vec<Cluster> = Vec::new();
    let mut queue: Vec<[usize; 2]> = Vec::new();

    let mut marked_cells: [[u8; SIZE]; SIZE] = [[0; SIZE]; SIZE];

    for i in 0..SIZE {
        for j in 0..SIZE {

            if marked_cells[i][j] == 1 { continue; }

            let code = playground[i][j];
            let mut cluster = Cluster::new();

            queue.push([i, j]);
            marked_cells[i][j] = 1;

            while !queue.is_empty() {
                
                let coords = queue.pop().unwrap();

                cluster.coords.push(coords);

                for direction in &directions_cluster {

                    let check_i = coords[0] as i8 + direction[0];
                    if check_i < 0 || check_i as usize >= SIZE {continue;}

                    let check_j = coords[1] as i8 + direction[1];
                    if check_j < 0 || check_j as usize >= SIZE {continue;}

                    let ni = check_i as usize;
                    let nj = check_j as usize;
                    
                    if playground[ni][nj] == code && marked_cells[ni][nj] == 0 {
                        queue.push([ni, nj]);
                        marked_cells[ni][nj] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if cluster.coords.len() >= 5 {
                cluster.code = code;
                clusters.push(cluster);
            }
        };
    };

    return clusters;
}
```

But I don't like this part:

```rust
for direction in &directions_cluster {

    let check_i = coords[0] as i8 + direction[0];
    if check_i < 0 || check_i as usize >= SIZE {continue;}

    let check_j = coords[1] as i8 + direction[1];
    if check_j < 0 || check_j as usize >= SIZE {continue;}

    let ni = check_i as usize;
    let nj = check_j as usize;
    
    if playground[ni][nj] == code && marked_cells[ni][nj] == 0 {
        queue.push([ni, nj]);
        marked_cells[ni][nj] = 1;
    }
}
```

I even had to define additional variables (check_i, check_j) to not use casting for ni/nj each time later.
What the best way of type casting in may case?

Comment: I'd suggest you start by questioning your declarations, for example, why do you declare `coords: [usize; 2]` if you can always cast its values to `i8`? And why mix signeness like that?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, we can use only `usize`  for array's indexes. I get `coords` from some `queue: Vec<[usize; 2]>` of coordinates

Comment: I voted "needs details" because this question IMO does not have enough of a question in it to be properly answerable. Yes, there are several casts in there. The problem is that if these are the data types you have to work with, and this is the algorithm you have to do -- you pretty much *have* to do those conversions. This code honestly doesn't look that bad to me, if the types and behavior can't change. It would hardly be improved by having pervasive implicit conversions à la C. Specifically, what's *wrong* with it?

Comment: @trentcl I changed question. Yes, maybe this is not wrong, I just want to know some elegant ways with work with arrays and indexes (without multiple type castings)

Comment: @trentcl I just want to notify you that the question has been reopened, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html) trait from the standard library to abstract away from the overflow checking. This is how I would implement it:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

type Pos = [usize; 2];

fn add_to_coords(coords: Pos, offset: [i8; 2]) -> Option<Pos> {
  let ni: usize = (coords[0] as i8 + direction[0]).try_into().ok()?;
  let nj: usize = (coords[1] as i8 + direction[1]).try_into().ok()?;
  [ni, nj]
}

// ...

  for [ni, nj] in directions.flat_map(|dir| add_to_coords(coords, dir)) {
    // ...
  }

// ...
```

The call to `flat_map` filters out all the return values that were `None`, in case you were wondering where the `continue` went.

Comment: Thanks, good solution. I also tried use array of earlier calculated neighbour coords for each cell